# Wordpress Widget Styles

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

When I add a widget in wordpress it put custom styles in the html. I can't find the styles in my style sheet.  The style is something link widget widget_links, where should I look to find these styles?  Can I edit these styles without editing the core?

Comment: Try this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/ . It has widget styling options on the pro version that you can utilize if you don't want to depend on the theme. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the theme, but there may not be rules for those specific cases in the stylesheet. If not, just add them.

You don't need to go *anywhere* near the WordPress core to edit the stylesheet, you simply use the stylesheet(s) contained in the theme.

Comment: There are some widget styles in the css, but not the ones I see in the html.  I do see this in my themes fuction php `'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">'`  but i am not sure what the %1$s or %2$s is for.

Comment: Then all you need to do is add in the ones that you need but are not there. The "1%$s" is where a variable is injected in to add numbering for targeting specific widgets.